# OpenCV get black pixels within contour boundary

Tags: android, image-processing, opencv, pixel

I am currently trying to retrieve all the black pixels which are present within the contour boundary. I am not interested in the contour boundary, but rather in the black pixels which lie within the boundary and make up the actual image. It would be great if I could get the actual co-ordinates of the image.

I have tried using copyTo method using a mask, but I believe I am not setting the correct parameters. While, I also tried using Core.fillPoly which just fills up the entire contour area with the color specified in the command and it isn't helpful to get the pixel information. Could anyone please guide me here? I am working on Android 2.2 with OpenCV 2.3.1.

Answer (score 5):

There is a set of pixels that fall within the contour boundary.  There is another set of pixels that are black.  You want to find the intersection of these two sets, that is, the set of pixels which are both within the boundary and are black in color.

To do this I would:

1. Draw the contour as a filled shape, white on black (in its own image) so that it is a mask.
   You can use `cv::drawContours` or `cv::fillPoly`.
2. Filter the black pixels from the image as another mask.
   You can use `cv::threshold` with `THRESH_BINARY_INV` and a threshold value of zero.
3. Find the intersecting set using `bitwise_and` or simply the `&` operator like `matResult = mat1 & mat2;`

The result is a matrix of the same size as your image with non-zero values only for the pixels which satisfy your criterion of being within the contour and black in the image.  You can get the individual coordinates by looping though this matrix and testing for non-zero values.

Comment: Thanks Brian, looks promising. I will try it out and let you know.

Comment: Hey Brain, this is the piece of code I have implemented, which seems to be working as of now as tested on the android emulator. But, when I try to convert the final matrix into a set of vector, the app crashes. I am converting it so that I can view the non-zero pixels which the Mat holds. Please advice. It fails on this line - `Converters.Mat_to_vector_Point(finalResult, points);` I have obtained the final mat with this command - 'Core.bitwise_and(mGrayC4,contourRegion,finalResult);`

Comment: I assume you have initialized the `points` list? You could try checking the intermediate matrices to check that they hold what you expect.  Otherwise it is hard for me to know what the problem is without seeing more of your code.